# Como calcular a diferença de horas no MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Como calcular, a diferença de ***horas*** no [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/)?

Answer (score 4):

Para calcular a diferença de horas no [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/) utilize a *function* [`TIMEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) que retorna o diferença entre as horas, junto com a *function* [`CURTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime) que retorna a hora atual.

***Exemplo:***

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), hora) as dif 
               FROM conversas WHERE de=7 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

*Referências:*

- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/)
- [`TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)
- [`CURTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime)

Answer (score 0):

Cara eu estava com a mesma dúvida e isso me ajudou

http://jquerydicas.blogspot.com/2013/11/mysql-diferenca-entre-datas.html

ex..
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,cas_data_de_abertura, cas_data_de_fechamento), usu_nome, cas_status,cas_data_de_abertura,cas_data_de_fechamento
FROM caso INNER JOIN usuario ON caso.usu_id = usuario.usu_id 
WHERE cas_status = 'Fechado' AND cas_id = 75