# php - verificar se a data passou 30min

Tags: php

Como faço para que o UPDATE apenas Edite as datas que ultrapassaram 30 MINUTOS!???

Comment: Você tem a chamada do javascript ao php?

Comment: ah? Isto é so php... só quero php

Comment: No fechamento acima tem link para solução PHP e MySQL. Se tiver mais alguma especificidade não coberta pelos links, queira [edit] a questão e acrescentar dados e tags apropriados. Lembrando que além dos links acima, há muitos outros posts no site sobre diferença de tempo, o campo de pesquisas pode ser útil.

Comment: Mas eu gostaria de obter a informaçao em relaçao ao UPDATE e não a IF data lalala...

Como faço no UPDATE WHERE data_1 < TIME(Horas) 30min

Comment: Basta copiar da condição do [segundo link de fechamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21762/70): `WHERE TIMEDIFF( data1, dataatual ) > intervalodesejado` - Lembrando ainda que se pesquisar no site, vai achar outros exemplos similares.